# Pandas: create new column with specific time index values if a value exist in a specific column with a mapping condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my input (pandas DataFrame):

```
timestamp             identification   value   identification_bis  value_bis
2021-10-07 10:00:01   123456789         1000                            
2021-10-07 10:00:05                            123456789            900 
2021-10-07 10:00:10                            123456789            100
```

Here is what I would like to get:

```
timestamp             identification    value    event_time           value_bis
2021-10-07 10:00:01   123456789         1000     2021-10-07 10:00:05  900
2021-10-07 10:00:01   123456789         1000     2021-10-07 10:00:10   100
```

So the presence of value in the column identification_bis means there was an event and I should create a new column with the time of this event mapping on the identification column.
I've tried using pivot table but I feel it s probably not the best approach

thanks in advance, really having hard time on this one

Comment: The question is still a bit vague. Consider rephrasing

Answer (score 1):

Split your dataframe in 2 parts and merge them:

```
# Create a boolean mask
mask = df['identification'] != ''

# Split in 2 dataframes
df1 = df.loc[mask, ['timestamp', 'identification', 'value']]
df2 = df.loc[~mask, ['timestamp', 'identification_bis', 'value_bis']]

# Rename columns for the final output
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'identification_bis': 'identification',
                          'timestamp': 'event_time'})

# Merge dataframes on right
out = df1.merge(df2, how='right', on='identification')
```

Note: the key here is the boolean mask. I used the empty string to determine in which dataframe each row should go. You can use whatever you want as mask but the idea still the same.

Output:

```
>>> out
             timestamp identification value           event_time value_bis
0  2021-10-07 10:00:01      123456789  1000  2021-10-07 10:00:05       900
1  2021-10-07 10:00:01      123456789  1000  2021-10-07 10:00:10       100
```

Comment: Thank you Corralien!
The merge looks fine but it looks like it doesn't keep the the timestamp nor the event_time. Maybe because these two were DateTime index ?